# spider animation, gif, javascript or css3

Tags: javascript, animation, web-crawler

Hi I am new to web development. I want to include a small spider that drops from the navigation  menu, which is going up and down and when the user clicks on her to stop. What is the easiest way to do this? I was thinking to do this with a gif picture but I don't know how to include the mouse click.Can you please help me.

Comment: gif to animate the spiders legs, css to animate the spiders movement, javascript to stop the css movement (though this may be possible with css as well, depending on the exact layout of the page)

Comment: Look up JQuery. You're probably going to use javascript too. http://try.jquery.com/